# mod_rewrite capture first letter in query and build url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to figure out how to capture the first letter of a category and make urls like this

```
http://www.domain.com/category/t/test
```

The original url is:

```
http://www.domain.com/category/category.php?category=test&category_id=1
```

I am not very good with mod_rewrite and nothing I try works. I keep trying to read the documentation etc but I still do not succeed. I cannot even find an example anywhere of how to capture the first letter and build links how I want them. I see sites using it but I cannot seem to figure it out or find an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear which is the source and which is the target URL. Surely you want users to use the first, RESTful, kind, and internally to use the second kind?

In any case, the way to capture a character is via (.). Then refer to it as $1 in the target URL, or, if you have used more than one capture, $n where is the capture number in the source URL reading from left to right and starting from one.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure I cought right your idea ...

```
$NewUrl = "http://www.domain.com/category/".$_GET["category"][0]."/".$_GET["category"];
```

$_GET["category"][0] = first letter

:update:

URL: http://www.domain.com/category/t/test

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$0 [L,QSA]
```

.php

```
$ref = explode("/",$_GET["param"]);
```

Comment: That will not work. It needs to be mod_rewrite using .htaccess I know how to get the first letter using php but I am clueless on how to build urls like this using mod_rewrite.

Comment: I understand that .htaccess does not create urls. The url is created already and the "original url" from my post is a working link. I am trying to use .htaccess to make the "original link" look like the example link I posted. So basically the url exists and there is no need for any php. I just need the correct rewrite rule to format it how I would like it which would be the very first link of my post.

Comment: @Jirka .htaccess can contain rewrite rules. Your answer is entirely off topic.